# Pass Dynamic Function Name in Node

Tags: node.js, cypress

I have a method for creating a database connection, and want to keep it generic to allow calling separate query methods from it.  Tried doing:

```
async function connectAndQuery(functionCall, config) {
  const mongoUri = `mongodb+srv://` + config.mongoUser + `:` + config[`${config.environment}MongoPassword`] + `@company-user-` + config.mongoEnvUriSection + `.mongodb.net/db-name-` + config.environment + `?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
  const client = new MongoClient(mongoUri);

  try {
    await client.connect();
    return await functionCall(client);
```

Where `functionCall` is the name of the method with the query, but `functionCall` is not recognized as a function.

EDIT:
Added calling code which uses the `task` function from Cypress IO.
From plugins/index.js

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {

  on('task', {
    queryDb({functionCall, config}) {

      return connectAndQuery(functionCall, config)
    }
  })

  config = dotenvPlugin(config)
  return config
}
```

From support/index.js

```
cy.task('queryDb', {functionCall: 'getPasswordLink', config: Cypress.env()})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Comment: Please show how you are calling this `connectAndQuery()` function.  That's likely where the issue is.

Comment: @O.Jones I did see something similar with the brackets, wasn't able to get that to work.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm calling it using `task` function as this is a Cypress IO project:
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html#Syntax

Comment: Well, the error is that you're not properly passing a function reference to the function you show.  I don't think we can help you unless we see the actual code that is calling it.

Comment: Fair point, added.